# django-rest-framework json responses sometimes including metadata, sometimes not

Tags: json, django-rest-framework

I am trying to deploy an application to a production server, but testing has revealed a strange inconsistency in django_rest-framework (first with version 2.3.14, now upgraded to 3.0.1).

On my development machine the json response comes wrapped with some metadata:

```
{u'count': 2, u'previous': None, u'results': [json objects here]}
```

Whereas on the production machine only the 'results' array is returned.

Is there a setting or to change this one way or the other?

Serializers are as follows :

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Sample

class LibrarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sample = SampleSerializer()
    class Meta: 
        model = Library
```

views.py

```
class PullLibraryView(generics.ListAPIView):   
    serializer_class = LibrarySerializer 
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('submission_slug', '')
        return Library.objects.filter(sample__submission__submission_slug=slug)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This metadata is added to the response through the pagination serializer, which is a part of the [pagination that is built-in](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/). The metadata will only be added if pagination is enabled, so you need to check your settings to make sure that pagination is enabled on your production machine.

Pagination is [determined by your settings and `paginate_by` property](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagination-in-the-generic-views) on your views. Make sure your requests do include the `page_size` parameter, which should force pagination on your views.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had checked that, but obviously not well enough.